# JQuery datepicker breaks in a for loop in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am trying to use jquery datepicker in django, but it breaks in a for loop.

The datepicker shows in all the fields where it is called, but after the first field, all of the other fields don't work correctly. It starts me off in the right month but when I click the forward or back arrows it goes to the years 1900 and 1899, respectively.

What could be the issue here?

This is my forms.py:

```
class AddSessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    start_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control datepicker_input', 'placeholder': 'Start Date'}))
    end_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control datepicker_input', 'placeholder': 'End Date'}))
    price = forms.CharField(required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Price'})) 

    class Meta:
        model = ClassSession
        fields = ('start_date', 'end_date', 'price', )
```

In the html I have:

```
{% for session in sessions %}
  <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Start Date </label>
          {{form.start_date}}
          {{form.start_date.errors}}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="state"> End Date </label>
          {{form.end_date}}
          {{form.end_date.errors}}
      </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

...

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".datepicker_input").datepicker();
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run .datepicker() on each DOM-element with the class datepicker_input, not only on the first one. Therefore:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $(".datepicker_input").each(function() {
            $( this ).datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
```